# Start a python script at startup automatically?

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron, startup

I followed multiple tutorials available on stackoverflow about starting a python script at startup but none of them works.

I need to activate a virtualenv then start a flask server

1. I tried
   init.d method

I made an `start.sh` in `/etc/init.d/`

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          skeleton
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Should-Start:      $portmap
# Should-Stop:       $portmap
# X-Start-Before:    nis
# X-Stop-After:      nis
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# X-Interactive:     true
# Short-Description: Example initscript
# Description:       This file should be used to construct scripts to be
#                    placed in /etc/init.d.
### END INIT INFO

cd /home/ion/
source /home/ion/py35/bin/activate
cd /home/ion/Desktop/flask/
nohup python main.py &
echo "Done"
```

Its permissions are chmod at +x

```
ion@aurora:/etc/init.d$ ll start.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 625 Jun 25 19:10 start.sh*
```

Went to `/etc/rc.local`

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
/etc/init.d/start.sh


exit 0
```

Didn't work

2. cronjob method

   sudo crontab -e

and appended

```
@reboot sh '/etc/init.d/start.sh'
```

Didn't worked either , where am I wrong?

Manual triggered logs

```
(py35) ion@aurora:~/Desktop/flask$ python main.py 
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/ion/Desktop/flask/encoder.py:57: calling l2_normalize (from tensorflow.python.ops.nn_impl) with dim is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
dim is deprecated, use axis instead
2018-06-25 19:34:05.511943: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
 * Serving Flask app "main" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://localhost:5505/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
```

Comment: Does ` python main.py` work ok if you run it manually?

Comment: Yes , Once the env is activated main.py works fine

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1) Don't use old "init.d" method. Use something modern. If you have Ubuntu 15.04 and higher, you can use Systemd to create daemon that will be started automatically at startup. If you have for example Ubuntu older than 15.04 - use Upstart.

For Systemd:

Create unit file in `/lib/systemd/system/you_service_name.service` with the following content (as far as I can see your python script doesn't spawn new process while running, so `Type` should be `simple`. More info [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Options)):

```
[Unit]
Description=<your_service_name>
After=network.target network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=<required_user_name>
Group=<required_group_name>
Restart=always
ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/<your_service_name>
PIDFile=/var/run/<your_service_name>/service.pid
ExecStart=/path/to/python_executable /path/to/your/script.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Save this file and reload systemd:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Then add your service to autostart:

```
sudo systemctl enable you_service_name.service
```

you should see that Systemd created required symlinks after `enable` action.

Reboot and see if it's up and running (`ps aux | grep python` or `sudo systemctl status you_service_name.service`). If there is something weird - check Systemd journal:

```
sudo journalctl -xe
```

**UPD:**

To launch your python script in desired virtualenv, just use this expression in your service unit file:

```
ExecStart=/venv_home/path/to/python /venv_home/path/to/your/script.py
```

2) You can also use `crontab`, but you need to specify full path for desired shell there, for example:

```
@reboot /bin/bash /path/to/script.sh
```

If you need additional help - just let me know here.

Comment: Crontab worked like charm but If I want to use systemmd then I can see the path of python file but how to activate the virtualenv

Comment: @Abhay please see UPD above.

Comment: @Arstsiom I tried this method but there is problem with this. If we want to print something on terminal, it does not print that. Secondly if there are more than one files in a folder and main file is dependent on other files, it can not import from those files. Is there any solution for this? I am running it on orange PI