# Python SSH reboot and restart python script

Tags: python, ssh, websocket

I have a python script using websocket. After few hours my websocket connection is sometimes lost and I am not able to capture the disconnection.

I would like my ssh machine reboots every 12 hours and starts again my python script.

Is it the best way to process?
How can I do it on a ssh machine?

Can I use

```
0 */12 * * * sudo reboot
```

and after automatically start my python script?

Comment: Not sure if it is the best way to do it, but you could temporarily put it `/etc/init.d` as a startup script (don't forget to make it executable) `chmod +x /etc/init.d/start_python_script.sh`.

Comment: Oh, looks like my last post is a bit out of date... looks like one shouldn't do it that way anymore... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51025312/start-a-python-script-at-startup-automatically

Comment: Thank you, why It shouldn't be done anymore?

Comment: Tbh, it still works afaik but perhaps people want to encourage others to move to the newer systems approach!

Comment: ok I understand thank you

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo - newer systemd approach, I meant, but I guess it's the same meaning haha