# Why does crontab always restart my python script with a new PID

Tags: python, cron, debian

I've a python3 script and would like to start it automaticly after a reboot. It is starting, but it starts always with a new PID, I checked it with ps aux. If I start the file via terminal, it is just running in the same PID.

I used
@reboot /usr/bin/python3 /path/myFile.py
in crontab

```
import sys

from cryptography import x509
sys.path.insert(0, "..")
import time


from opcua import ua, Server


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # setup our server
    server = Server()
    server.set_endpoint("opc.tcp://0.0.0.0:4842/freeopcua/server/")

    # setup our own namespace, not really necessary but should as spec
    uri = "http://examples.freeopcua.github.io"
    idx = server.register_namespace(uri)


    # get Objects node, this is where we should put our nodes
    objects = server.get_objects_node()

    # populating our address space
    myobj = objects.add_object(idx, "MyObject")
    startCali = myobj.add_variable(idx, "Start Calibration", True)
    brigthness = myobj.add_variable(idx, "Brightneess", 0.0)

    brigthness.set_writable()
    startCali.set_writable()    # Set MyVariable to be writable by clients
    oldstartCalivar = 0
    oldbrightnesss = 1.0
    
   
 

    # starting!
    server.start()
    
    try:
        count = 0
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            
            if brigthness.get_value () != oldbrightnesss:
                changeBrightness = "xrandr --output eDP-1 --brightness %f" % (brigthness.get_value()) 
            oldbrightnesss = brigthness.get_value()
                
                     
    finally:
        #close connection, remove subcsriptions, etc
        server.stop()
```

Comment: I doubt it has the same PID if you run it through terminal. It gets new PID each time, because that's the identifier, and when it launches, there's x other processes with other PIDs. It just takes what's next in line.

Comment: PID is the process ID. So every new process (run) you get a new ID. Crontab just execute a new process. You may have a server that has name "python" which keep running, and you may confuse it with your program. Check with `pstree` command: you will see if it is a deamon, or just a command started from a shell (and from your shell)

Comment: I may was a bit unclear:
If I start the .py with crontab, it will start after a reboot. I do not start it manually at the same time. But now I check the PID with "ps aux | grep <filename> and it gives back the PID of the script, e.g. 1650. Now I execute ps aux again, and get back a PID e.g. 1652. And so on.

If I start the script just in terminal, it is just running with the same PID.

Comment: if you get answer in another question so I close this question with link to other question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with another approach:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51025312/start-a-python-script-at-startup-automatically

--> Answer by Artsiom Praneuski